# JBoss EAP 6.1 connecting to WebSphere 7 EJB

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, websphere

Has anyone ever actually successfully done this?  I've seen different suggestions on different sites.  I've tried using the WebSphere client, but that breaks everything else inside my JBoss application that needs to use JNDI lookups.

I've tried using Jacorb but it gets non-descriptive errors returned, I've tried searching those errors with no luck.

I've tried using the Sun context factory but I get class cast exceptions.

Nothing I have tried works.  Has anyone gotten this to work?  I was able to get it to work in a standalone app using several different methods.

Comment: Just a thought, if you are using you should probably contact jboss support directly, they will have more expertise on these types of things I suppose.

Comment: also saw the issue, don't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible using the [AluniteClassLoader](https://github.com/wolfc/jboss-alunite/blob/master/classloading/src/main/java/org/jboss/alunite/classloading/AluniteClassLoader.java):

```
ClassLoader previous = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();            
try {
  ClassLoader cl = new AluniteClassLoader(new URL[]{new URL("file://path/to/websphere/client.jar")}, previous);
  Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl);

  //Service lookup & method invocation
} finally {
  Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(previous);
}
```